# SP2-0310: unable to open file "explannew/rdbms/admin/utlxpls.sql"

Tags: sql, sqlplus, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to run an explain plan in the sqlplus environment but i am getting the error SP2-0310: unable to open file "explannew/rdbms/admin/utlxpls.sql".

(*I replaced the actual figures with the zeros below*)

Please help explain what i am getting wrong. A typical example of the explain plan is below;

```
set lines 130
set head off

spool explan1.txt

explain plan for
  select
    entity_cre_flg, TO_CHAR(product), TO_CHAR(product_for_int_rate),
    TO_CHAR(diff_product), TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    TO_CHAR(wtax_pcnt), TO_CHAR(wtax_floor_limit),
    TO_CHAR(last_comp_tax), TO_CHAR(tax_amount), wtax_for_cr_comp, rowid
FROM
  TBAADM.TBA_INTEREST_DETAILS_TABLE
WHERE
  entity_id = '000000' AND entity_type = 'ACCNT' AND interest_ind = 'C'
  AND interest_type = 'N' AND serial_num = '0000' AND bank_id = '0000' ;

@?/rdbms/admin/utlxpls

spool off
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're not running the statement on the same machine where your Oracle installation is. If this is the case, the file `rdbms/admin/utlxpls.sql` is most probably missing.

You can check if you find the directory

```
$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin
```

(if you're on Unix) or

```
%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin
```

(if you're on Windows).

Alternativaly, I suggest that you don't use `utlxpls`, but use

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)
```

instead.